# Substrate run benchmarking error - 'setjmp.h' file not found

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template

Working on substrate-node-template , When I run benchmark I get the below error. It says 'setjmp.h' file not found. I am working on Macbook pro

```
cargo build --release --features runtime-benchmarks
```

error: failed to run custom build command for `wasmtime-runtime v1.0.2`

```
  Caused by:
    process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/yusufkelo/Documents/Developer/workspaces/substrate-projects/substrate-node-template-2023/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/release/build/wasmtime-runtime-04bf801e868dc470/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
    --- stdout
    cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/helpers.c
    TARGET = Some("wasm32-unknown-unknown")
    OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
    HOST = Some("aarch64-apple-darwin")
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_wasm32-unknown-unknown
    CC_wasm32-unknown-unknown = None
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_wasm32_unknown_unknown
    CC_wasm32_unknown_unknown = None
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_CC
    TARGET_CC = None
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
    CC = None
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_wasm32-unknown-unknown
    CFLAGS_wasm32-unknown-unknown = None
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_wasm32_unknown_unknown
    CFLAGS_wasm32_unknown_unknown = None
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_CFLAGS
    TARGET_CFLAGS = None
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
    CFLAGS = None
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
    CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
    DEBUG = Some("false")
    running: "clang" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-DCFG_TARGET_OS_unknown" "-DCFG_TARGET_ARCH_wasm32" "-o" "/Users/yusufkelo/Documents/Developer/workspaces/substrate-projects/substrate-node-template-2023/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/build/wasmtime-runtime-b8e432731307a73b/out/src/helpers.o" "-c" "src/helpers.c"
    cargo:warning=src/helpers.c:1:10: fatal error: 'setjmp.h' file not found
    cargo:warning=#include <setjmp.h>
    cargo:warning=         ^~~~~~~~~~
    cargo:warning=1 error generated.
    exit status: 1

    --- stderr
```

using polkadot polkadot-v0.9.35"
After running `rustup +nightly show` I get the below

```
installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2021-11-29-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2022-01-31-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2022-03-10-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2022-08-09-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
bpf
sbf
1.65.0-aarch64-apple-darwin
1.66.0-aarch64-apple-darwin

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

aarch64-apple-darwin
thumbv7em-none-eabihf
wasm32-unknown-unknown

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin (overridden by +toolchain on the command line)
rustc 1.70.0-nightly (f63ccaf25 2023-03-06)
```

Comment: Please include: `rustup show` and `rustup +nightly show`

Comment: I just built the Substrate Node Template (`polkadot-v0.9.37`) on my Mac M1 using the same command and it worked fine. Please include more info for debugging purposes.

Comment: @Bruno rustup +nightly show added

Comment: the error occurs when I run cargo build --release --features runtime-benchmarks i.e with the --feature  the runtime-benchmarks

Comment: Yes I have it works on my machine with `cargo build --release --features runtime-benchmarks. Please also include the `rustup show`

Comment: Try building with the tag `polkadot-v0.9.37` and see if you have the same issue.